# CasperJS: How to read filename from headers when downloading?

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I'm using CasperJS to download a file. I need to extract the filename from the HTTP Response headers (i.e. `Content-disposition: attachment;filename="pronk.txt"`). There is no way to determine the filename from the URL itself (points to a database hash) or the hyperlink (just says "click here").

CasperJS has a great built-in `download()` function, however it requires a user-supplied filename. This parameter is not optional, and the download fails without it.

Is there another way to go about this where I can get the file data AND the HTTP headers?

Comment: does that "click here" link is permanent and point to a dynamic resource link?. I had a situation where a download button everytime contains a unpredictable dynamic links and I used jQuery to find the link and passed it to the download() function.

Comment: The link is permanent, although it requires a valid logged in session to access (hence why I'm using Casper instead of CURL). I have no problem accessing the link itself; its that the download() function requires the user to supply the filename, instead of taking whatever the server suggests...